# Team City - File not found error - compilation error

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity

My team city build is failing with error

> " [Csc] CSC error CS2001: Source file
>   'Services\Entities\ModelNames.cs' could not be found

Thing is this .cs file is deleted from source contrl (TFS) and local machines when checked in. There is no piece of code using this class anywhere in the project. But I still keep getting this error. What can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your TeamCity checkout or script checkout is correct.  It seems like your building using old project file.  Maybe the sub directories are checked out and not the root directory as well ?

Comment: Enforce over write all files should be checked ? for this.

Comment: If your paths are correct, yea probably, I don't know that option though.  Although it might be the same as the one I have ( might depend on the TeamCity version ) --> Clean all files before build:

Comment: okay.. I have that too. I did both, hope this will fix it. Thanks

Comment: It hasnt fixed the error.. tried clean check out, over write , even changed check out locations.. but still getting same error..

Comment: Does the project still reference the file ?  If you have VS installed on the build machine you might want to open that up and see, or just open it in notepad and check if you find reference.